# radical of a certain ideal of sixteen variable polynomial ring, generated by the entries of certain matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, matrices, polynomials, noncommutative-algebra

Consider the polynomial ring $R=\mathbb C[x_1,x_2,...,x_{16}]$, and set

$$X=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 &x_2&x_3 &x_4\\ x_5&x_6& x_7&x_8\\x_9&x_{10}&x_{11}&x_{12}\\x_{13}&x_{14}&x_{15}&x_{16}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, using these three matrices

$$L=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&-1\\0&0&-1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
$$N=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

we create polynomials $f_i, g_i,$ and $h_i$ in the following way:

$$XLX^t-L=\begin{pmatrix} f_1 &f_2&f_3 &f_4\\ f_5&f_6& f_7&f_8\\f_9&f_{10}&f_{11}&f_{12}\\f_{13}&f_{14}&f_{15}&f_{16}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$XMX^t-M=\begin{pmatrix} g_1 &g_2&g_3 &g_4\\ g_5&g_6& g_7&g_8\\g_9&g_{10}&g_{11}&g_{12}\\g_{13}&g_{14}&g_{15}&g_{16}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$XNX^t-N=\begin{pmatrix} h_1 &h_2&h_3 &h_4\\ h_5&h_6& h_7&h_8\\h_9&h_{10}&h_{11}&h_{12}\\h_{13}&h_{14}&h_{15}&h_{16}\end{pmatrix}$$

Finally, let $I = (f_i, g_i, h_i)$ be the ideal generated by these $48$ polynomials. Then how to show that the radical of $I$, i.e. $\sqrt I$, is generated by twelve linear polynomials and one quadratic polynomial ?

Nullstellensatz may be of help ... but I can't quite see it ...

NOTE : All the matrices $L,M,N$ are orthogonal , so the three defining equations can be written as $(XL)(LX)^t=(XM)(MX)^t=(XN)(NX)^t=Id$. Now if we can find some pattern in $XL,LX,MX,XM,NX,XN$ then it could be helpful to find the zero set of the ideal $I$ ... 
Also $L,M,N$ are skew symmetric matrices and , $LM=-N$ ... this means $L,M,N$ works as the $i,j,k$ in the Quaternion ring ...

Comment: Could you give some motivation for why you believe that the radical should be generated in the degrees you list?

Comment: @dhy: well ... no motivation ...I was just told by my professor that it is true ... he asked me to try it out saying it would be interesting ... and he also asked me to see if I can say anything about $I$ itself ... unfortunately I haven't even been able to do even the radical ...

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) `associatedPrimes` yields $\langle {x}_{12}+{x}_{15},{x}_{11}-{x}_{16},{x}_{10}+{x}_{13},{x}_{9}-{x}_{14},{x}_{8}+{x}_{14},{x}_{7}-{x}_{13},{x}_{6}-{x}_{16},{x}_{5}+{x}_{15},{x}_{4}+{x}_{13},{x}_{3}+{x}_{14},{x}_{2}-{x}_{15},{x}_{1}-{x}_{16},{x}_{13}^{2}+{x}_{14}^{2}+{x}_{15}^{2}+{x}_{16}^{2}-1\rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let us do all the calculations over $\mathbb{R}$ onstead of over $\mathbb{C}$. It will facilitate things, and will not change the result.

Let us rewrite the equations a bit:
You have $$X\cdot (LX^tL^t)=Id$$ and similarly for $M$ and $N$.
In particular, your system is now equivalent to the sent of equations; 
$$LX^tL^t = MX^tM^t = NX^tN^t= X^{-1}.$$
The first two equalities mean that $X^t$ commutes with the matrices $M^{-1}L$ and $N^{-1}L$ (since for these matrices the transpose is the inverse). 
This is a set of linear equations on $X^t$ (and hence on $X$).
Since $LM=-N$ and so on, this is equivalent to the fact that $X^t$ commutes with $L$, $M$, and $N$.
Let now $H$ be the four dimensional quaternion algebra with basis $\{1,i,j,k\}$. Then $L$, $M$, and $N$ represent the multiplication from the left by $i$, $j$, and $k$ respectively. Since the quaternions form a division algebra, the only thing which commute with multiplication from the left with $L$, $M$ and $N$ is multiplication from the right with someone from the quaternion algebra. Let us write such an element as $a+bi+cj+dk$. Then you get that your matrix $X$ has the form 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b & -c & -d \\
b & a & d& -c \\ 
c & -d& a& b  \\
d & c& -b& a  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Writing the original entries of $X$ in terms of these numbers gives you the desired 12 equations. We are now left with the equation $$XLX^tL^t=Id$$ which is quadratic. Notice that since $X$ commutes with $L$, and since $L$ is orthogonal, this is equivalent to $$XX^t=Id.$$
But this can easily be seen, by a direct calculation, to be equivalent to $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = 1$.
Since the polynomial $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-1$ is irreducible, you get that the ideal $I$ is radical, and tha it is generated by 12 linear polynomials and one quadratic polynomial.

Comment: So if I understand correctly ... you are first trying to find the zero set of $I$ right ? Um why doesn't working with $\mathbb R$ change the result ? Also , I could follow your argument upto the point that $X$ commutes with $L,M,N$ which can be considered as the $\{i,j,k\}$ basis elements of the Quaternion algebra ... but then I don't get what do you say about why $X$ has to be of that special form ?

Comment: I don't under stand where you say  "Since the quaternions form a division algebra, the only thing which commute with multiplication from the left with L, M and N is multiplication from the right with someone from the quaternion algebra" .. what do you mean by this ? Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Since the entries of the matrices are all real, you can show easily that the generating set you give for I is a collection of polynomials with real coefficients. so $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots, x_{16}]/\tilde{I}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$ is the same as the ring you are interested in. In any case, viewing this over $\mathbb{R}$ is just good for a point of view. The fact that if $X$ commutes with $L$, $M$ and $N$ it must be of the specific form follows also from a direct calculation. Notice that when I say that $X$ must be of this form, I just say that $X$ satisfies some linear equations.

Comment: About the second part: Let us write $\mathbb{R}^4 = H$ for the Quaternions. Then we can think of $L$, $M$ and $N$ in the way described. A matrix $X$ which commutes with $L$, $M$ and $N$ is the same as a homomorphism $H\to H$ of $H$ modules. But such a maps always has the form $x\mapsto xy$ for some fixed $y$. Then a direct calculation shows that for $y=a+bi+cj+dk$ the map we get is of the above form. Again, this can also be seen by a direct calculation, using $X=LXL^{-1}$ et cetera.

Comment: but $LX$ is not in $H$ ... so how do you get a homomorphism $H \to H$ ? Please could you elaborate ... I can't understand this point ... and how did you conclude at the last step that $I$ is a radical ideal ?

Comment: You do not need that $LX$ is in $H$. We think of $X$ as a linear transformation $H\to H$. The fact that this linear transformation commutes with $L$ $M$ and $N$ is equivalent to this being a homomorphism of $H$-modules. About $I$ being a radical ideal: what we actually do is the following. Write $J$ for the subideal of $I$ generated by the linear polynomials in $I$.  Then you can consider the image of $I$ in the quotient ring $R/J$. It is enough to prove that $I/J$ is a radical ideal there, and this follows from the explicit description of the equations of $XX^t=Id$

Comment: Yes but if say $LX$ or $XL$ is not in $H$, then how can you think of $X$ as a linear map $H \to H$ ? If you are considering the map $h\to Xh, \forall h\in H$, then in that case it should only be a linear map from $H $ to $M_4(K)$ ... am I missing something obvious here ... ?

Comment: because if you already know $X$ is a linear map $H\to H$, then apriori $X=X.1\in H$ ... so how do you know that $X$ maps every element of $H$ into $H$ itself ?

Comment: Write $H = \mathbb{R}^4$. Call the standard basis elements $\{1,i,j,k\}$. Then $X,L,M$ and $N$ are $4\times 4$ matrices, and therefore can be considered as linear maps $H\to H$.

Comment: ah that makes sense ... thanks ... then why $X$ commuting with $L,M,N$ implies that the map on $H$ is a $H$ module homomorphism ?

Comment: that's more or less the definition of being a module map. X is a module map if $X(Lv) = L(Xv)$, and same for $M$ and $N$. Then, since  $1,i,j,k$ span the quaternion algebra, it is a module map.

Comment: thanks ... though I still don't understand why $I$ is radical ... by determining $X$ etc. you are actually finding the "Zero Set" of $I$ hence those 12 restrictions actually give the generating polynomials of the idealizer of the zero set of $I$ which is $rad(I)$ ... I don't see why those polynomials should generate $I$ ...